GSAP and ScrollTrigger scrolling issues with animation
I'm currently building a landing page with some "flying" cards that start from a random x and y position, and end in another random x and y positions. Already I'm running into some issues, which I will list below (please bare in mind that I'm not a highly experienced programmer and a lot of GSAP is a lot of copy pasting from the internet):

I have set up the code so that when the scrollbar reaches the end of the page, it resets back to the top while maintaining the cards in the same position to create an infinite, seamless loop. Right now, when the scrollbar resets back to top there is a slight jump on the position of the cards in desktop, and on mobile it automatically animates quickly back to the same position (please look at the link i share at the end of this message)

I wrapped all the content in a .wrapper div, and I tied ScrollTrigger to listen to this container's scroll instead of the window, but now when you scroll both on desktop and mobile, the parent container, in this case, the 'body' scrolls automatically when I scroll, creating a jump (please look at the link I share at the end and scroll to see the issue, especially in mobile). I tried to fix this by using overscroll-behavior: contain, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is not a bug per se, but I would like to have the animation autoplay and only accelerate the animation in both directions on scroll, at the moment the animation is fully controlled by the scroll (scrub: true), but I would love it if it was like I describe here.


You can see and inspect the code of my page here: https://fernandaruiz.work/projects/kin3
Thank you in advance to anyone who can help me with this!
I tried using overscroll-behavior: contain; to avoid the jumping of the page on scroll but it doesn't seem to work (maybe I'm not applying it properly?)

Could you show code responsible for this logic?

@ŁukaszD.Mastalerz yes apologies,  I forgot I had to remove the wrapper so I can show a preview to the client, but you can see the version where I'm using the wrapper in this link: https://fernandaruiz.work/projects/kin3
You can see the two main issues:

The scroll is jittery
The seamless loop is not seamless at all, it animates back where it should snap back

